# Modifying existing Django site

Tags: django, web, installation

I am completely new to this Django world. I haven't tried it ever before.

Now the problem is as below;

One of my clients was hosting his site somewhere else that I don't know and they built the site using Django. The host company doesn't allow to make any changes on their server, instead they provided the zip file for all the files in the site to me; so that now I can  host my client's site.

As I don't know anything about Django, can someone please shed a light where I should start from?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers. 
Sach

Comment: What's your setup? Linux I hope? Apache? Ngix?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, install Django on the development machine. Start by trying to get the development server run on your machine.

Gather requirements: check the settings.py for installed apps against the default Django settings.py file. See if there are any popular django apps that site depends on. If there are any, then you probably will have to install them, too. 
In which format was the database provided? Will you move to another more appropriate format? Python bindings for databases are required too.

Considering the fact that you have inherited this project and probably will need to make some changes, consider installing [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/), so you can easily make changes to the database schema.

If you get the site running properly on your own machine, consider deplyoment. Is there a lot of static content? (if so, consider [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/NgxWSGIModule)). Set up apache2 and install the [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) module. Deploy.

Work your way through the Django tutorial first. Then look into Django Book as has been mentioned. Django IRC channel (#django) on Freenode is also great for help.

Answer (score 2):

Django is fairly easy to setup if you already have the code written. You'll need to install the chosen database and then simply follow the tutorial on the [Django website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/)

Django comes with a built-in server so it's very easy to run the website for development without needing Apache, nginx or much else.

Comment: The built in server is for development only.

Comment: True, but did the user ask because he's only looking to host or is looking to develop as well? I don't deserve downvote for all true statements.

Comment: I assume he just needs to make development changes then hand the code back to them to host it in its original location, but I could be wrong!

Comment: @JohnGiotta: Until you fix that statement, and state that the built in server is for development only, my downvote remains. To my understanding the OP wants to host it somewhere else.

Comment: @the_drow - Edited I threw in "for development"

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to learn about Django before trying to jump in head first - https://www.djangoproject.com/ contains documentation as well as tutorials on creating Django apps.

Answer (score 1):

I learned using the [Django Book](http://djangobook.com/).  Django is an easy-to-use framework, you should be fine.

Also, in the short-term there's a file called views.py and separate folder containing templates.  If you're familiar with MVC (MVT in Django) this contains the views for the site in function form.  There's probably (but not always) a folder for templates which contains a lot of the HTML for the site.  Just a good starting pointing for basic modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps start here.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/
First, find out the django version required by your client.  Install that on a server (not a production one), setup apache and mod_wsgi.  The zip files may go to a dir which can be included in the mod_wsgi configuration.

Find about the static files and setup apache or any other lightweight webserver to server it.

You may not be a developer, but have a try with the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/). It can give you a good idea how its structured.